# Is it “were” or “are” in: “Where are/were you when I needed you?”

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

> Where were you when I needed you?

I used the phrase

> *Where are you when I needed you?*

Is the grammar correct? I don't know if it is.

Answer (score 3):

No. The first statement is right and the second is wrong.

When you say "*when I needed you*," you are referring to the past. You intend to know where the person *was* at that time. So the statement

> *"Where **were** you when I **needed** you?"*

is grammatically correct.

The question *"Where are you?"* is at the present tense, so there is a conflict of tenses when you state

> *"Where **are** you, when I **needed** you?"*

which doesn't make grammatical sense.

Comment: You might ask: "Where are you when I need you?" if you felt that someone  whom you rely on was forever letting you down.

Comment: @RonaldSole True. Notice that the tenses of *are* and *need* are in harmony in your example.